# Set default Bullet Point Style in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I know how to define a new bullet type in word. But how can I change the **Default** bullet style?

I can use Word VBA if I need to but I wold prefer not to. I also do not want to keep changing the bullet style multiple times.